# How do I add numbers from two txt files and write it to the same file?

Tags: awk, sed, paste

I want to add numbers from two txt files. The number will change in file1, and file2 should update itself like this `file2 = file1 + file2`. Decimals not needed.

Example:

file1

```
3
```

file2

```
7
```

Output:

file1

```
3
```

file2

```
10
```

I tried `$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{$0 = $1 + $2}' > file2` but all it does is copy the number from file1 to file2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
let tot=$(cat file1)+$(cat file2)
echo $tot
```

Answer (score 5):

In-place replacements are not natively supported in `awk`. You can use `sponge` from `moreutils` to rewrite to a file you read in.

`awk`-way to add two files line-by-line

```
awk ' FNR==NR { a[NR]=$1 } FNR!=NR { print $1+a[FNR] }' file1 file2 | sponge file2
```

Simpler non-`awk` way, that also supports floating points:

```
paste -d'+' file1 file2 | bc -l | sponge file2
```

Both methods support multi-line files.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with command and it worked fine too

```
paste f1 f2| awk '{print $1+$2}' >f2_tmp && mv f2_tmp f2


praveen@praveen:~$ cat f1
3
praveen@praveen:~$ cat f2
10
praveen@praveen:~$
```